# Como borrar un segmento de una lista doblemente enlazada en C++

Tags: c++, c, lista

Tengo una cadena (lista doblemente enlazada) formada con nodos del tipo TLocalizador y debo borrar un segmento que va desde "desde" hasta "hasta"

Pero no me funciona, alguien me puede ayudar?? Esta es la función que escribi

```
TCadena borrarSegmento(TLocalizador desde, TLocalizador hasta, TCadena cad){
    //assert(precedeEnCadena(desde,hasta,cad));
    if (!esVaciaCadena(cad)){
        TLocalizador desde_anterior = anterior(desde,cad);
        TLocalizador hasta_siguiente = siguiente(hasta,cad);
        TLocalizador aux = desde;
        while(desde != siguiente(hasta,cad)){
            desde = siguiente(desde,cad);
            cad = removerDeCadena(aux,cad);
            aux = desde;
        }
        if(esInicioCadena(desde,cad)){
            cad->inicio = hasta_siguiente;
            hasta_siguiente->anterior = NULL;
        }
        if(esFinalCadena(hasta,cad)){
            cad->final = desde_anterior;
            desde_anterior->siguiente = NULL;
        }
        if(!esInicioCadena(desde,cad) && !esFinalCadena(hasta,cad)){
            desde_anterior->siguiente = hasta_siguiente;
            hasta_siguiente->anterior = desde_anterior;
        }

    }
    return cad;
}
```

Comment: Solamente elimina los componentes desde "desde" hasta "hasta" y luego enlaza el siguiente de "desde" con el anterior de "hasta"